# How to get list generating in different thread and populate in the listview?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have a very large list which I set it to generate in different thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
   public void run() {
      getTheList();  //a method in my class which generates Arraylist<> list.
   }
});
t.start();
```

Now I used Timer task to shedule the list to populate every 5 seconds.

```
class task extends TimerTask {
                public void run() {
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = ListViewActivity.this.getList();
                String[] from = {"date","sname","bname","contrno","item","quantity","rate"};
                int[] to = {R.id.textViewSRdate,R.id.textViewSRSname,R.id.textViewSRBname,R.id.textViewSRcontrNo,R.id.textViewSRitem,R.id.textViewSRquantity,R.id.textViewSRrate};
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list ,R.layout.some_row, from, to);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
             }

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new task(), 5000, 3000);
```

it says "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." when i want to set the adapter for my listview inside task class. "listView.setAdapter(adapter)"
**I just want the list should load new data automatically every X seconds.**
How this should be done?

Comment: You are updating the UI in another thread..which is not acceptable..Use Handler instead of timer..

Comment: You shouldn't change the adapter but edit its data. That can be done in any thread.

Comment: @Pietu1998 but after updating the adapter data i should have to setAdapter again... and in equal intervals of time.

Comment: @donison24x7 You should have a reference to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() after you change the data instead of setting the adapter, reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: No. The adapter's entire purpose is to automatically update the view when you update the data.

Answer (score 3):

the following should work for the problem with the thread:

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {              
   @Override
   public void run() {
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
});
```

It will execute in the listView thread -> Main Thread

But Pietu is right:

> You shouldn't change the adapter but edit its data. That can be done
>   in any thread.

This guys explains it quite well, search for "notifyDataSetChanged()":

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: read this answer: "@donison24x7 You should have a reference to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() instead of setting the adapter, reference: developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/…"
Change the data in an array or whatever, and call notifyDataSetChanged() to "reload" it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your ListView for the first time and start the following timer. You can set your interval in milli seconds and the **onTick** function will be called regularly with the interval set.

```
new CountDownTimer(total_duration_in_millis, Interval_in_millis) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long arg0) {
                                //code to get updated list
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    //optional
                }
            };
```

Better extend your activity class with ListActivity, so that you can populate your list using **SetListAdapter()** method and no need to access the ListView by id.